# Setting file status to permanent fails

Tags: 7, files

I am trying to set the status of an uploaded file to 1 but looking in the file_managed table it stays 0. The file does get uploaded properly but gets removed after a while.

My form field:

```
$form['nor'] = array(
  '#type' => 'file',
  '#title' => 'Upload pdf',
);
```

And my function:

```
function mymodule_addForm_submit($form, &$form_state) {    
  $nor = file_save_upload('nor', null, 'public://docs');

  if ($nor){
    $nor->status = FILE_STATUS_PERMANENT;
    file_save($nor);
  }
}
```

Debug of $nor:

```
stdClass::__set_state(array(
 'uid' => '1',
 'status' => 0,
 'filename' => 'my_file.pdf',
 'uri' => 'public://docs/my_file.pdf',
 'filemime' => 'application/pdf',
 'filesize' => 57930,
 'source' => 'nor',
 'destination' => 'public://docs/my_file.pdf',
 'timestamp' => 1363198206,
 'type' => 'default',
 'fid' => '148',
 'field_license' => 
   array (
     'und' => 
       array (
         0 => 
           array (
            'value' => 'nothing',
           ),
       ),
   ),
  )
 )
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: does $nor contain `$nor->fid` ?

Comment: I edited my post with the debug of $nor